# How to fetch data from API and save into data base in rest framework in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to fetch data from API and save it to the database as given below code in rest framework in Django?

```
if user is None:
 URL = "http://172.31.0.3:8000/studentapi/"
 URLDATAS = "https://reqres.in/api/users?id=2"
 data1 = {}
 if uname is not None:
  data1 = {'id':uname}
  json_data = json.dumps(data1)
  headers = {'content-Type':'application/json'}
  r_get = requests.get(url = URLDATAS, headers=headers, data = json_data)
  data = r_get.json()
                         
  r_post = requests.post(url = URL, headers=headers, data = data)
```

Comment: Any one can help please

Comment: Can you show me the error?

Comment: @DavidLu  error is notging but  its saving data like this {
        "email": "null",
        "first_name": "null",
        "last_name": "null",
        "avatar": "null"
    },

Comment: You Can directly use MyModel.objects.create(email=data.get("email"), first_name=data.get("first_name"))

Comment: Did you get a solution to this